# Auto-compiling web2py app using grunt

Tags: compilation, gruntjs, web2py

I have a web2py app running via uwSGI, which I want to make as speedy as possible, since it is providing an frequently used API service, stored in a controller called API.py. I've seen that it is possible to byte-compile the python code used in web2py. I assume this will speed up the results returned from the API, but I would like to ensure that and code changes result in my app being recompiled.

I assume this can be done somehow using Grunt to fire off the command-line method for compiling web2py apps as listed at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/rMog7ID9WUE. Presumably I would need to specify which files to inspect for changes to trigger recompilation. Has anyone set up this sort of thing before, and is it a bad or good idea from a web2py point of view? I'm suspicious that I can't see any online discussion of other people doing this.

Comment: That approach seems fine. web2py compiles files in the /controllers, /models, and /views folders, so those would be the ones to watch.

Comment: Just noticed that, since some of my views use conditional {{extend}} statements, I need to use `gluon.compileapp.compile_application('applications/myapp', skip_failed_views=True)`. Otherwise seems to work. I'll post some grunt code as an answer once it is all working